# Accessing FormGroup instance from within directive attached to <form>

Tags: angular, angular-directive

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" />
  <div *errorFeedback name="name" class="error-feedback"></div>
</form>
```

Form Directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'form'
})
export class FormGroupErrorDirective implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {

  @ContentChildren(ErrorFeedbackDirective) errorFeedbackDirectives: QueryList<ErrorFeedbackDirective>;

  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    this.errorFeedbackDirectives.forEach(dir => {
      // ???? How can I get this.formGroup ???
      dir.formControl = this.formGroup.get(dir.formControlName);
    });
  }

}
```

*errorFeedback Directive

```
// tslint:disable:directive-selector
@Directive({
  selector: '[errorFeedback]',
})
export class ErrorFeedbackDirective implements OnInit {
  // tslint:disable:no-input-rename
  @Input('errorFeedback')
  name: string;

  formControl!: FormControl;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
              private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

How can I get access to the `FormGroup` directive instance from within `FormGroupErrorDirective`?

What I'm trying to do here is pass the FormControl instance to the `*errorFeedback` directive. I'll then use it for observing status changes and errors there.

Or is there any better way to get access to FormControl instance inside `*errorFeedback`?

Comment: Injecting `@Host() private formGroupDir: FormGroup`should work, although some NgForm injection token might exist that makes this more correct.

Comment: You might want to have a look at ngx-valdemort. Either because it could do what you want to achieve directly, or because you might want to take inspiration from its sources. https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com/#/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FormGroupDirective` class in your directive constructor:

```
constructor(private fg: FormGroupDirective) {
    this.fg = fg;
    console.log(this.fg.form)// print your form group 
}
```

In your template:

```
<div [formGroup]="editFormGroup" yourDirective>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Both import { FormControlDirective, FormGroupDirective } are very useful in directives.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to access the `FormGroup` by declaring in directive constructor method a property like this:

```js
import { ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private readonly form: ControlContainer) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a directive that allows you to access the FormGroup from within the directive. At the moment its a bit of a hack, but it works well. My directive allows you to set the form value based on an observable

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-directive

You can adapt it for your needs

```
constructor(private vr: ViewContainerRef) {}

ngAfterContentInit() {
  let componentProperties = (this.vr as any)._hostView[8];
  let form: FormGroup;
  
  // Find the form in the component
  for (let property of Object.keys(componentProperties)) {
    if (componentProperties[property].__proto__.constructor.name === "FormGroup") {
      form = componentProperties[property];
    }
  }
  
  //DO SOMETHING WITH form
}
```